# How to print esc sequences in Visual Studio console in python?

Tags: python, python-3.11, vt100

I am running python 3.11 script from Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 10. I want to print VT100 esc sequences to control the caret in the console.

However I get this:
[image]

It looks to me as if the console that I am in, doesnt support VT100.. Google says Windows 10 console supports it. But the console that is launched by VS looks different (the icon of the window for one).

My guess is that VS uses its own console and not the system's one.. Is it possible to configure VS to use Windows 10 console? Or else - how to modify the code so it prints control character on non-VT100 console?